# Connect KafkaProducer using Servlet

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to connect KafkaProducer using servlet and setup my project in eclipse. But when i run KafkaProducer i get an exception:

> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke SEVERE:
>   Servlet.service() for servlet [simple_kafka.SimpleProducer] in context
>   with path [/kafka_web] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an
>   exception] with root cause java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer   at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1291)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
>     at simple_kafka.SimpleProducer.doPost(SimpleProducer.java:56)   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

my KafkaProducerServlet is as follow:

```
package simple_kafka;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
//import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class SimpleProducer
 */
@WebServlet("/producer")
public class SimpleProducer extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public SimpleProducer() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG);
        String topicName = "ReplicaTopic";
          String key = "Key1";
          String value = "Value-1";

          Properties props = new Properties();
          props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "192.168.1.59:9092,192.168.1.59:9093");
          props.put("key.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");         
          props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

          KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer <String, String>(props);
          try {
              ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>(topicName,key,value);
              producer.send(record);           
              producer.close();
          }
          catch(Exception e) {
              response.getWriter().append("Exception at: ").append((CharSequence) e);
          }
//        response.sendRedirect("/consumer");
    }
}
```

I had Included Following JAR's in BuildPath of project Property:

1. Kafka 2.12-0.11.0.1.jar
2. kafka-clients-0.11.0.1.jar
3. slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After day long searching i found that you need to include the JAR files WEB-INF-> lib folder and you need to delete your server from eclipse & reconfigured it. After doing that i am able to run the KafkaProducer.